# Different behavior of package import by F5 and F9 in Spyder

Tags: python, import, spyder, attributeerror

I am using the package cvb in Spyder with Python 3.6.

I got
`import cvb`
on top of my script

If i use F5 to run the whole script I get an error (`AttributeError: module '_cvb' has no attribute 'NotifyArgs`) for this import.

If I select `import cvb` and then run selction with F9 there is no error and I can run the script afterwards with F5 also without error.

What is the difference between the call by F5 and F9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to adjust PYTHONPATH and now it works.